# parseSdkContent failed error in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

When I opening eclipse it opens, but it shows one error i.e Android SDK content Loader has encountered a `problem.parseSdkContent` failed

When I click on details button, it shows me `parseSdkContent` failed `java.lang.NullPointeException`.

And when I tried to create AVD it shows error that Location of the android SDK has not been setup in the preferences while I have already set the path in preferences.

Please help me. Because of this issue my work is pending.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite late to answer but I had a similar problem...

You can refer this **[Android L parseSdkContent failed Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288837/android-l-parsesdkcontent-failed-could-not-initialize-class-android-graphics-typ)**