# Android L parseSdkContent failed Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface

Tags: eclipse, android-5.0-lollipop

Hello recently i updated to Android L sdk. Now whenever i open new project dialog i'm getting this error.

**parseSdkContent failed
Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface**

I have seen many questions already answered on stackoverflow but the solutions mentioned didn't work for me.

- I have tried deleting the .android in folder C: drive and restarted eclipse.
- I have also tried re-installing the new version of Android ADT plugin through Help->Install New Software in Eclipse as mentioned at http:\developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html
- Whenever i check for new updates in Eclipse it shows "No New Updates Found".

But still i'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 4):

The update issue is probably related to your parseSdkContent issue, since "the update mechanism in the ADT bundle is broken" ([Comment 66](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419#c66)). This means that Eclipse have not updated to be compatible with the new Android

I had the same problem when I wanted to update my Eclipse to prepare it for Android L, so I downloaded the new adt zip, then came accross the other error, and after deleting my .android folder, I am no longer having issues.

The new bundle can be found on the android developer site, and here is the link: [Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download)

Comment: thanks for showing interest @anon but i got my problem solved by switching over to a new workspace.

Comment: @Akshay Soam: Thanks for letting me know, sometimes it is as simple as that -_-.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was fixed in the API 21 rendering library. As a workaround, you can use the rendering library from API 20 in the meanwhile.

1. Download the SDK platform for API 20 (4.4W)
2. Navigate to your sdk folder (should be like
   D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk)
3. Go to platforms folder -> android-21 folder -> data folder
4. Rename layoutlib.jar (for backup purpose)
5. Copy the same file from your android-20 folder to this folder
6. Restart Eclipse

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77726#c15

Comment: I tried taking `layoutlib.jar` file from `android-20/data` but getting the same "parseSdkContent failed
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError" with ADT 23.0.4 and SDK Tools 23.0.5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691865/eclipse-gone-crazy-since-sdk-lolipop-update/27102803#27102803