# Android L - parseSdkContent Failed on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-5.0-lollipop

Everytime I create, edit, add anything inside any project's folder, I always encounter this problem. **"parseSdkContent failed. Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface"**.

I've been searching all around in the internet, and tried their given solutions e.g. Deleting .android folder in Drive C., Restarting the ADT, and even the system and so on. But still the problem is annoying me.

I hope somebody can help me regarding this matter. Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem when i updated my sdk to Android L.

You can have a look at **[Android L parseSdkContent failed Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288837/android-l-parsesdkcontent-failed-could-not-initialize-class-android-graphics-typ)**

Be sure that the update is complete and you are not working with half download android - L sdk