# Eclipse gone crazy (since SDK Lollipop update)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-5.0-lollipop, android-typeface

I can't write code for days.

Eclipse usually return this errors, when I trying a edit layout. And create new project, new xml file, trying to run project:

> "parseSdkContent failed
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"
>
> "parseSdkContent failed
> Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface"

Im delete my user/.Android folder. It works but until to next edit xml. When try to open layout xml,  return errors again. A few edit after give it to "....typeface" error.

I try to delete my workspace/.metadata, I try clean install ADT, not update to Lollipop, x68/x86-64...

Errors are continues, I feel desperate.

How can fix this?

SOLVED!

Im solved with switching new workspace. Deleting .metadata is not enough.

Comment: Have you tried Android Studio? I know this isn't the answer you're looking for (hence a comment), but I've been happily using the Android 5.0 APIs in Android Studio for a while now.

Comment: Not yet. I'm get used to eclipse, but if it's not work. Maybe the time has come to change Eclipse. :/

Comment: I'm managing a project and about a month ago we decided to change to android studio because our projects was maven managed and google simple drop maven support to graddle and eclipse sucks with graddle. Now the team is fully adjusted on AS, took a few days but worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, making new workspace is much better then deleting `.metadata` anyways.
But in my case it did worked, but could run into error again, that would require restart.

Android 5.0 tools (including Android Studio) seems to be still buggy,
so get older version e.g. 22.6.3 from [here](https://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.6.3.zip) into new Eclipse instance and work with new workspace.

Check NodeClipse [Android Start](https://nodeclipse.github.io/projects/gradle/android/start).

After some time when new ADT version comes try to update it in the 1st eclipse instance.

That is having one Eclipse with stable plugins for work
and other Eclipse with newer plugins for learning and experimenting.