# "parseSdkContent failed Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface" in SDK Andorid 5.0

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm getting the below error after I update the **SDK Android 5.0 (API 21)**

```
"parseSdkContent failed Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface"
```

Another thread suggested to delete **.android** folder, yes its works, but after sometime this error will trigger again and not able to select any Project Build Target SDK, (its allows to check the target and apply, but again open Properties->android, its showing unchecked) to build the app.

I'm using Android SDK Build Tools Rev 19.1 and Eclipse Juno. ADT version 23.0.4

Note : If my Android Project target SDK version is 20 or 19, there is no problem.

Comment: finally I received the correct answer from Google+ Android community. Now, its working great...

Comment: So what is the answer?

Comment: Possibly has answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288837/android-l-parsesdkcontent-failed-could-not-initialize-class-android-graphics-typ

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691865/eclipse-gone-crazy-since-sdk-lolipop-update/27102803#

Answer (score 1):

This is android package error,its corrupted android 5.0 sdk platform. Just Delete the folder `<sdk>/<platforms>/<android-21>` and download the android 5.0 sdk platform from sdk manager.

Answer (score 1):

Got the fix. This happened because you installed a new Eclipse and loaded the 5.0 API Directly. You just have to delete the file:

".android in C:\User\\" in Windows.

After this step just install the **ANDROID SDK BUILD-TOOLS revision 21**

Hope it works for you :)[image]